# Installing rdiff on docker containers

Tags: python, gcc, docker, librsync

I am trying to make a backup solution off docker containers using rdiff. I have python install and the python-dev packages but when I run the install command:

```
python ./setup.py install
```

I get the following error

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'rdiff_backup._librsync' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c _librsyncmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_librsyncmodule.o
_librsyncmodule.c:25:22: fatal error: librsync.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Do you have the development package or source for rsync installed?

Comment: This is the package i installed apt-get install python-dev

Answer (score 2):

Your container needs the `librsync-dev` package.